# Natively Retrieve a List Of Firefox Profile Names in Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I'm using `Java + Selenium` and I'm trying to determine whether a Firefox Profile exists with a given name. Is there a native way to programmatically determine if a FF Profile exists with a certain name?

I'm aware of at least two workaround methods. One is to parse the contents of `profiles.ini` located under `AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\` for a list of properties that begin with `Name`. The other option is to try to launch a FF Profile with the name in question and programmatically check if this causes FF to launch. However, both of these methods are not native to Firefox or Selenium and have certain weaknesses (such as excess CPU utilization and the possibility that FF may change where they store Profile data among other concerns)

Is there a native way to achieve the desired outcome?

Thanks